# To get to do something

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I found the sentence:

> We got to meet all the stars after the show.

Does it mean we met them or we just had the opportunity to meet them and we didn't necessarily meet them?

Answer (score 1):

To *get to* do something is to be given the opportunity to do it (with the implication that you took that opportunity).